# Why my UIMenuItems are showing in the 'more' section of UIMenuController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am showing UIMenuController while a table cell is long pressed. I am using the code below.

```
- (void)onCellLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

        ContactTableViewCell *cell = (ContactTableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
        [cell becomeFirstResponder];

        UIMenuItem *item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ME" action:@selector(setMe)];
        UIMenuItem *item2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"YOU" action:@selector(setYou)];
        [theMenu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, nil]];

        UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [theMenu setTargetRect:[cell frame] inView:[self tableView]];
        [theMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My problem is, When I long press a cell, menu pops up with all the default menu items. My menu items "SAVE" and "DELETE" are not showing when the menu pops up. They are showing when I select the "more" menu. I posted the screen shots below.

**SCREEN SHOT 1**: Menu that pops up when I long press a cell.

[image]

**SCREEN SHOT 2**: Menu when I press the "more" menu item in SCREEN SHOT 1.

[image]

I want the menu in SCREEN SHOT 2 to open when I long press a cell.

1. What wrong am I doing here?
2. What am I missing here?
3. What I should do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the default items, you need the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method to return NO. Which means that you need for the objects in the responder chain to not perform the requested actions, or a custom implementation of the method.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks.. But if I return NO, the menu is not showing at all.. I need to return NO for any particular case alone?

Comment: @Graham Lee: Thank you.. Actually I didn't understand the use of canPerformAction:withSender: method before. I understood it now.. Its working.. One more thing, now only I understood your first line **"To disable the default items, you need the canPerformAction:withSender: method to return NO."** :) Thanks for your help..

Comment: @Simon, can u share what u have change into your code? i'm still not understand how to not showing the item in particular case, can u help me?

Comment: @Risma: Yes. Have you subclassed *UITableViewCell*?

Comment: @Simon, not yet, do you use UITableViewCell? I use UITextView in my problem, why i have to make a subclass of it?

Comment: @Risma: You need to subclass it so that you can override the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method. And inside that method return **YES** if you want a particular **action** to be shown in the pop-up menu. Return **NO** otherwise.  For example `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
 
 if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
  
  return YES;
    }
 
 return NO;
}`. This code will show only the **copy** menu when you long press the view.

Comment: @Simon do you know about right-left-toggle that also appear on UIMenuItem popover? can i do something like this to that item?

Comment: @Risma: Sorry. I don't have any idea about that.

Comment: @Risma: Hi.. Try this `if ((action == @selector(copy:)) || (action == @selector(_setRtoLTextDirection:)) || 
(action == @selector(_setLtoRTextDirection:))) return YES;`

Comment: @Simon, are _setRtoLTextDirection & _setLtoRTextDirection methods given by IOS? i did not find any documentation about it

Comment: @Rishma: Yes those methods are given by iOS. You can get the action names for different actions shown in menu by printing them from inside `canPerformAction:withSender:` method like this `NSLog(@"Action: %@", NSStringFromSelector(action));`. You will see all the available actions.